# Does it exist a way to get back or reset the white Wifi notification icon?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking

I'm having this problem after uninstalling several programs (with Microsoft Edge among them) I got this problem that the Wifi icon isn't showing connected status anymore. It is stuck as if it isn't connected at all and it displays an empty icon as indicated in the figure.

[image: Photo of the problem]

Although I had verified the connection it shows connected and I can use the internet. How can I get that white connected indicator icon back?.

So far I have used the following commands and it hasn't worked

netsh winsock reset

netsh int ip reset

ipconfig/ release

ipconfig/ renew

I had also uninstalled the network adapter from control panel in hardware settings and reinstalled again and the problem persists.

[image: Second photo of the problem]

Does it exist some file or perhaps and individual missing file which has perhaps been deleted or something?.
I had previously installed strawberry pearl, could its uninstallation had been linked to this problem?.
I'm currently on Windows 7. Can someone help me here please?. I'm stuck, and ran out of ideas. Please don't say just reinstalling the OS, while I can attempt to do that, its not the solution which I'm aiming at.

I've already attempted to reset the notificcation tray icons using an utility suggested but this **did not solved the issue**. I've also went to services and verified that **network notification awareness is set to automatically** and is okay. I've attempted to reset from services panel but it seems that it cannot be completed as there were other applications using it. I've restarted the laptop and attempted the same but it seems that it cannot be reset. Does it exist a way to solve this weird issue with the wifi icon?. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's been accidentally deleted to some extent since those icons are stored in those dll files like shell32.dll, imageres.dll, netcenter.dll etc. Well, the next thing we're going to check now, are some Windows Services related to WiFi and Networking. To open Windows Services Manager(Local), open command prompt and then type services.msc. Once there, check these Windows Services -- DHCP Client, Network Location Awareness, Network List Service, Network Store Interface Service, and lastly Windows Event Log. Set all the aforementioned Windows Services to |Automatic| and set them all to |Start| as well. Or set all of them to |Stop| and then set them all back to |Start| once and for all vice-versa. Once done, log off or restart your lappy. The Windows WiFi icon should display the correct status after that I guess or else. Best of luck XD

Comment: I finally solved my issue. But I did it before catching your second answer. What I did was to uninstall the VPN software which I had installed and also a usb dual band wifi which I used from time to time, then I deleted all the leftover connections which were on network shaing center. Then while connected I retried all the commands mentioned in my question. After doing all of that I rebooted the laptop. When it loaded back I had the network icon with an x over it. So at that point I uninstalled the laptop network controller from hardware settings so it would reinstall again

Comment: Reinstalling the internal wifi controller and clearing out third party Wifi and VPN and reapplying all the commands mentioned did the trick. I was unsure that after uninstalling any software or performing a registry clean with CCleaner for example would delete the icon of network awareness but as you mentioned that icon is on the shell32 file. I have no way to confirm this. I had not verified if the other services were set to automatically but I guess they were if this issue arises again  I will check it.Hopefully as you indicated that will suffice to solve this issue.

Comment: My bad the particular icon is indeed stored in netcenter.dll not in shell32.dll. But I'm glad you'd resolve it by yourself without reinstalling the OS. Yes, I suspected about it too that those third party WiFi controllers/managers and VPNs were the main source of the problem since they also manage the network connection just like Windows Network/Internet Manager which may lead to management conflicts and dilemmas.You went through a lot of things in this one, but still better than reinstalling the whole thing. Great job!